# How to disable lock the Home button in iOS 7

Tags: ios, lockscreen, home-button

How can I lock the home button in iOS 7 ?

I have 10 text fields and a submit button in a view. While I'm filling the text fields, the home button should be disabled.
Only after filling all the text fields, should the home button be again enabled.

Please let me know anybody, how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please anybody know that,why my question is down voted??? It is very important to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling the Home button using your app is not possible but you can use [Guided Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5509) to block the Home button, but this is something the users will have to do. I don't think there's an API to do it within an app.

From Apple:

> Guided Access helps students with disabilities such as autism remain
>   on task and focused on content. It allows a parent, teacher, or
>   administrator to limit an iOS device to one app by disabling the Home
>   button, as well as restrict touch input on certain areas of the
>   screen.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable replay.As per your answer home button will disable for selected app.But is there any way or API for disable Home button for one viewController only.

Comment: @Laxmi: I don't think so.